# Installing msdeploy.exe on a production web server (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, msdeploy

There are always security concerns about everything and many are subjective given varying risk tolerances.

Ideally, though, should `msdeploy.exe` be installed on production web servers? If not, is there a set of command line parameters equivalent to that of:

1. Right-click web application in Visual Studio
2. Publish (File System)...

I realize one could just write a script to extract these same files from the web deployment package (*.zip), but if there was an easier way to do it with `msdeploy.exe` (i.e. extract files only), that would be preferred.

Comment: Consider the fact that Microsoft Azure allows you to use MSDeploy package to deploy web apps, you can tell if it is secure. You just need to assert the risks in your case, and take actions to remediate. If you use other approaches, I don't think the risks would be lower than MSDeploy.

Answer (score 0):

We have used MSDeploy for 50+ deployments over 3+ years to all environments (including PROD) with great success.  Lex makes a good point in the comment above that Azure uses it as well.

Ultimately it comes down to your situation/business but many shops are using it in PROD.